# Debugging in django/python

Tags: python, django

I come from a php background and liked that I could do var_dump pretty much anywhere in the code and get results.

It seems in python/django if I use the shell (./manage.py shell) I can debug methods that way, but it is not as fast.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: "I come from a php background" - sorry about that.

Comment: You can "print" or "pprint" "pretty much anywhere in code" in python.

Comment: https://github.com/Kozea/wdb

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, you were probably used to the awesome [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) extension.

In Python, spawn the classic debugger with (put this anywhere you'd put [xdebug_break()](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

My favorite is with the ipdb module (`pip install ipdb`):

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

You can also use [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) (`pip install werkzeug`) and [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) (`pip install django-extensions` and add `django_extensions` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`), which provides the `runserver_plus` command.

It's really, really great. That's one of the things that'll probably make you never look back at php again. Anyway, `runserver_plus` is like `runserver` but it will replace the default django stacktrace page with an ajax interactive shell available at each frame of the stacktrace. Of course you can get it by puting something like `crash` or `random_undefined_variable_name` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Python has an awesome step through debugger called [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). If you run Django in the foreground using the built-in webserver for development, you can throw statements in your code like

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and other pdb commands, and it will put you in the debugger. There's also a [django plugin](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb) for this.